# How to pass hex number to directive input?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Trying to pass a color value in hex to a directive, but having trouble understand why it won't recognize it

**In html**

```
<button md-button
        highlight 
[defBackColor]="#FFFFF7" [defColor]="#3498db
[background]="#2980b9" [foreground]="#FFFFF7"> {{filterType}}</button>
```

**In Directive**

```
import {Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[highlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {

  @Input() defBackColor: string = 'transparent';
  @Input() defColor: string = 'black';

  @Input('background') highlightBackColor: string = 'blue';
  @Input('foreground') higlightColor: string = 'white';

  @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') backgroundColor: string = this.highlightBackColor;
  @HostBinding('style.color') textColor: string = this.higlightColor;

  constructor() { }
}
```

Various error messages with the same context as following:
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:

> Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 1 in [#FFFFF7] in
>   ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@29:18 ("index" >
>           ][defBackColor]="#FFFFF7" [defColor]="#3498db" [background]="#2980b9" [foreground]="#FFFFF7"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string [defBackColor]="'#FFFFF7'"